# Makefile conditional assignment based on environment variable

Tags: makefile

I want the following behavior inside my makefile:

```
if the current user is "dev-builder":
  CACHE_DIR=/nfs/artifacts
else
  CACHE_DIR=
endif
```

In my Makefile, I have something like this:

```
ifeq($$USER,"dev-builder")
CACHE_DIR_FLAG="--output_base=/nfs/artifacts"
endif

mytarget:
  bazel $(CACHE_DIR_FLAG) build (other args)
```

But the command that comes out of make is just `bazel build (other args)` and does not seem to catch the `ifeq` condition, even though I verified that I am logged in as the builder account. If I remove the conditional `ifeq` and just blindly assign the `CACHE_DIR_FLAG`, the command is the desired one. Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try `ifeq($(USER),dev-builder) `, and if that doesn't work we can try building up from something simpler.

Comment: I just now came to the same conclusion. The quotes were causing the string comparison to fail.

Comment: `$$` expands to a single literal `$` -- you want `$(USER)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes in `ifeq` causes string comparison to fail.

```
ifeq($(USER),dev-builder)
commands here
endif
```